# How do CI server work without manually having to set up webhooks?

Tags: php, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am curious as how to CI servers like Jenkins and CI travis manage to watch for push events or changes at least to launch their build pipelines. So far what I have seen when you want to create your own server you have to set up webhooks that push data to an API endpoint.

Do CI servers like Jenkins and Travis automatically add webhooks to github or something or do they work differently? I would love to set up a really small PHP specific CI server but obviously I don't want people to have the hassle of setting up a webhook every time they add a repo. Simply adding your repo should suffice. Optionally logging in with a Github account.

**Edit**

I don't see why this is getting downvoted. I would love if somebody could go a little bit more in depth on how a hook works that is not set up through github's webhook interface.

Comment: Did you check my answer? I think it gives you what you were looking for (in the edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI systems usually comes with hooks that are already part of the system (or easy to install).

Specifically in jenkins there is a [GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) that gives you the ability to:

- Create hyperlinks between your Jenkins projects and GitHub
- Trigger a job when you push to the repository by groking HTTP POSTs from post-receive hook and optionally auto-managing the hook setup.
- Report build status result back to github as Commit Status (documented on SO)

(And probably more).

And plugin/ci system has it's own triggers/hooks for different workflows.